# jQuery - parseFloat returns different values when used

Tags: jquery, parsing, alert, parsefloat

In this code :

```
$("div#info_holder").css("marginLeft", "100%");
alert(parseFloat($("#info_holder").css("marginLeft")));
alert(parseFloat(document.getElementById("info_holder").style.marginLeft));
```

the first alert returns 1037.78, the second alert returns 100

why is that?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the jQuery version is returning the margin as pixels and the native JS is returning the value as a percentage. Take a look at this fiddle, which shoes the values before parseFloat is run.

```
$("div#info_holder").css("marginLeft", "100%");

console.log($("#info_holder").css("marginLeft"));
console.log(document.getElementById("info_holder").style.marginLeft);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/wtABu/

Comment: Correct. Just to go 1 step further, I assume that jQuery is looking at the box model of the `div` and doing some calculations behind the scenes, hence why your getting the pixel value of `1037.78`. When using native JavaScript, I assume it's pulling the value as set, the `100%`.

Comment: You could test this by taking out parseFloat and simply showing the alert value, but this would be my suggestion.

Comment: i see! i guess i will just use getElementById. thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

`$("#info_holder").css("marginLeft")` returns pixel while `document.getElementById("info_holder").style.marginLeft` read it in percentage.

Comment: no, this seems a lot complicated. jQuery is made to ease things, not make them even worse. i will just use getElementById. thanks a lot, though! :)

Comment: @user3130281 exactly and jQuery is wrapper of javascript so using javascript with jQuery not something to worry or bad practice.